# Https redirection not working on Apache 2.4

Tags: apache

I had some issues with my apache configuration and I'm trying to isolate the problem.

I came up with the following lines which are not working :

For testing purposes, I'm trying to redirect all https traffic to Yahoo

The redirection is not working and my web site is showing the index.html file stored in public_html

```
Listen 443  
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443> 
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/example.com/public_html"    
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example
    Redirect permanent / https://www.yahoo.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone help please ?

Thanks

Comment: If you're running an Apache 2.4, remove the deprecated [NameVirtualHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost).
Other than that, the `Redirect` looks good to me. Make sure `mod_alias` is enabled (`sudo a2enmod alias`) and reload/restart the server. Also check your configuration with `apachectl configtest`. It also doesn't hurt to have a look at the access and error log. To prevent cache effects of your browser, test with a command line tool like `wget`, `curl` or `lynx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for the redirect, also enable mod_rewrite for this to work:

Add this to the top of your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On #Don't use RewriteEngine On twice in one .htaccess file
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yahoo.com [R=301,L]
```

Clear your browser's cache to have a different redirect than yahoo.com, once it works.

### Just in case

If you want all traffic of your website to redirect to https:// on the same domain, do the following, don't remove `RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteBase /`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If you want to redirect all traffic to one domain with https:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST] !^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com [R=301,L]
```

If you want to redirect all traffic to one domain with https and www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST] !^www.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I don't want to do it on htaccess file. It just for testing purposes as I said. I need it to be done on Apache because I want to setup as reverse proxy based on this.

Comment: Do it on Apache's httpd.conf file. Remove RewriteBase

Comment: I'm sorry my knowledge is very limited on Apache. Will this allow me to configure a reverse proxy please ?

Comment: @ThomasCarlton Yes, it will I think. Add this to the end of httpd.conf. I will support you on any error. Reverse proxy should work because this is not internal redirect.

Comment: Thanks for your time. So do you know how should I add a reverse proxy then ? Thanks

Comment: @ThomasCarlton I see that you've already added it in your other question. Use that. Add this with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?